# Clear Variable Cache in Powershell

Tags: powershell

May I know if there is any way to clear variable cache in PowerShell as it is outputting the same value like the time?

This is my variable

```
$formatDate = $caller.EventTimestamp.ToString("s")
```

Thank you.

Comment: "Variable caching" is unlikely to be the source of your problem here. Please show us the whole function/script.

Comment: this is probably a scope problem with a reuse of parent variable

Comment: Please provide an example where the variable is set in the first place. I assume you are referring to `$caller`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable cache. You have a variable driver `variable:` for each variable scope.

If you used the variable in a "lower" scope already, it will be present in an "upper" scope as well (see [MS Docs - about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)).

Make sure you are not reusing variables throughout different levels or always start by resetting them in each scope.

```
$Variable = $null

# or

Remove-Variable -Name Variable -Force
```